# Select hierarchical data via Linq2SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

It's late here and I can't see the forest for the trees.

I'm trying to select hierarchical data with the following approach:

```
return
    from line in data
    group line by line.LieferscheinNr into g
    let kpf = g.First()
    select new DESSK1
    {
        K1LINK = MakeDfuePartnerID(kpf.Land, kpf.VerbandNr),
        K1LSNR = kpf.LieferscheinNr,
        K1LSDT = decimal.Parse(kpf.LieferscheinDatum.ToString("ddMMyyyy")),
        K1ILNW = kpf.IlnLieferanschrift,
        K1ILNH = kpf.IlnKunde,
        K1ILNL = kpf.IlnMandant,
        K1CPSD = 1,
        K1ILNB = kpf.IlnKunde,
        K1VSDT = decimal.Parse(kpf.LieferDatum.ToString("ddMMyyyy")),
        K1BSTN = kpf.BestellNr,

        // this is where the compiler complains
        DESSP2 = from pos in g
                 select new DESSP2
                 {
                     P2LSNR = pos.LieferscheinNr,
                     P2POSN = pos.Pos,
                     P2EAN = pos.EAN,
                     P2LMG = pos.Menge,
                     P2BMG = pos.MengeSoll
                 }
    };
```

I think you can see what I'm trying here but it fails since DESSP2 is of type `System.Data.Link.EntitySet<DESSP2>` and the query is of type `IEnumerable<DESSP2>`.

There must be an easy way from `IEnumerable<T>` to `EntitySet<T>` but I can't see one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I knew this was an easy one. While thinking about how to populate the EntitySet within the query I found this perfectly working solution:

[How do you cast an IEnumerable<t> or IQueryable<t> to an EntitySet<t>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100851/how-do-you-cast-an-ienumerablet-or-iqueryablet-to-an-entitysett)

I wonder why the `ToEntitySet()` method is not part of the language. Looks to me like an usual problem if you want to fill hierachical linq tables.

The relevant part now looks like this:

```
    DESSP2 = (from pos in g
             select new DESSP2
             {
                 P2LSNR = pos.LieferscheinNr,
                 P2POSN = pos.Pos,
                 P2EAN = pos.EAN,
                 P2LMG = pos.Menge,
                 P2BMG = pos.MengeSoll
             }).ToEntitySet()
```